# Постинг в Vk через Vk.Api - Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, vkontakte-api, вконтакте

Появилась надобность в разработке скрипта для постинга в сообщества(группы) сайта vk.com картинок.
Реализовал отправку простых сообщение (текстовых) а как быть с attacment'ми не могу понять помогите люди добрые.

И да картинка будут представлена в виде [https://домен/data/картинка.png](https://%D0%B4%D0%BE%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%BD/data/%D0%BA%D0%B0%D1%80%D1%82%D0%B8%D0%BD%D0%BA%D0%B0.png)

```
#/dev/usr/env python3
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
import vk

my_app_id = 5484091
user_login = 'email@mail.ru' 
user_password = 'password' 

session = vk.AuthSession(scope='wall', app_id=my_app_id, user_login=user_login, user_password=user_password)
vk.api.access_token="40d8beaebfdbb3815ef279032bbb6c8b3a13774e0d6ce0fbac6704882064f8fa6996866cb3b1b3bac7440"
api = vk.API(session)
api.wall.post(owner_id='-122263284',message="Просто текст...")
```

Comment: Делал через `vk_api`, вот [посмотрите](https://github.com/gil9red/SimplePyScripts/blob/master/vk_api/wall.post%20images.py).

Comment: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "photo.py", line 64, in <module>
    'attachments': hrefs.pop(),
IndexError: pop from empty list

Comment: написано же, что нельзя получить элемент методом `pop()` из пустого списка :) наверное, в яндекс-картинках что-то поменялось и теперь не находятся картинки ) добавьте в тот список свои ссылки и попробуйте снова

Comment: vk_api.vk_api.ApiError: [214] Access to adding post denied: access to the wall is closed
не хочет давать права на постинг...

Comment: хм... или стена закрыта или токен не имеет доступа к постингу на стену. у `vk_api` есть свой токен, возможно он или не рабочий, или вы свой подсовываете, у которого нет доступа. расширьте вопрос новым кодом или оформите как новый вопрос

Comment: http://pastebin.com/7cqUXEgv ну думаю так тоже можно...

Comment: отпишусь в ответе

Answer (score 4):

Попробуйте скрипт сначала на своей странице (укажите `OWNER_ID = None`). Потом на странице другого пользователя. Насколько я помню, у групп вк `OWNER_ID` отличаются от пользовательских – их id с минусом пишется:

```
import vk_api
import sys
import random


# Скрипт помещает картинки на стену пользователя vk.com


def vk_auth(login, password):
    vk = vk_api.VkApi(login, password)

    try:
        vk.authorization()  # Авторизируемся
    except vk_api.AuthorizationError as error_msg:
        print(error_msg)  # В случае ошибки выведем сообщение
        sys.exit()

    return vk


# Логин, пароль к аккаунту и id человека, на стену которого будем постить сообщения
LOGIN = ''
PASSWORD = ''
OWNER_ID = ''


if __name__ == '__main__':
    # Авторизируемся
    vk = vk_auth(LOGIN, PASSWORD)

    # Список с ссылками на картинки
    hrefs = [
        'https://danbooru.donmai.us/data/sample/--saber-and-saber-alter-fate-stay-night-and-fate-series-drawn-by-goldengear870--sample-5c66a91632c80384fd9a1e8c43bb5fd7.jpg'
    ]

    # "Перемешаем" элементы списка
    random.shuffle(hrefs)

    # Добавление сообщения на стену пользователя
    # Если не указывать owner_id, сообщения себе на стену поместится
    for href in hrefs:
        rs = vk.method('wall.post', {
            'owner_id': OWNER_ID,
            'message': 'Хей!',
            'attachments': href,
        })
        print(rs)
```

Если сервер вк не подхватил картинку и не стал ее отображать в посте, тогда нужно будет сначала залить на их сервер. Тут нужно использовать методы: `photos.getWallUploadServer` и `photos.saveWallPhoto`.

Пример:

```
def send_method(method, data=None):
    import logger
    import time
    logger.debug('Запуск %s с данными: %s.', method, data)
    rs = vk.method(method, data)
    logger.debug('Response: "%s"', str(rs).encode())
    time.sleep(0.5)
    return rs

# Путь к картинке
file_name = ...

rs = send_method('photos.getWallUploadServer')
upload_url = rs['upload_url']

rs = requests.post(upload_url, files={'photo': open(file_name, 'rb')})
rs = json.loads(rs.text)
rs = send_method('photos.saveWallPhoto', {'photo': rs['photo'], 'server': rs['server'], 'hash': rs['hash']})

# attachments поместить в `vk.method('wall.post'`
attachments = 'photo{}_{}'.format(OWNER_ID, rs[0]['id'])
```